# I've lost formatting in Firefox, but only for this site (ubuntu.stackexchange.com) !

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This is weird! ...

In Firefox, **for this site only**, I've am getting a screen full of basic text (and an occasional .png), but I've lost most of the decoration. There is still a semblence of  structure, but horizontal tables are now vertically aligned... There is **no bling**!
Plain ASCII may have its place, but not here!

Have I inadvertently tripped some menu option?  If I did, I can't find it again.

I've disabled  my add-ons, all bar the original `Ubuntu Firefox Mosifications`, but that hasn't helped...
I rebooted; still the samee.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems like you may have accidentally blocked the CSS file for the site.

Comment: @marco: Perhaps so, but I don't know how to unblock it if that's the case. Is there such an option built into the standard Firefox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Marco says it sounds like there is a problem with the CSS file(s). Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a reload of not only the page but the associated files (in this case the CSS stylesheets).

If that doesn't work you could try clearing your cache (an option in [Clear Recent History](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Clear+Recent+History)).

Comment: Thanks fluteflute... It was Ctrl+F5... a "secret" hot-key!  I can't find any reference to it in the menus, but then again I can't find F5 mentioned either, and F5 is pretty much the standard "page-refresh/reload" key in most (if not all) browsers.  Ctrl+R is shown instead, and yet F5 works too...  Okay. Problem solved.

Comment: You can use the more memorable `Ctrl+R` to Reload a page, and `Ctrl+Shift+R` to reload more (the page and all its dependencies, such as images and stylesheets, and ignoring any data cached on intermediate proxies too).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 3G wireless provider like O2 that proxies, caches and compresses lots of their users downloads?

I find that if I try using the website on my phone over 3G, it has no CSS, etc (as you describe)

Comment: @Oli: I'm hard-wired via ADSL, so that won't be the problem.., Thanks anyhow. ... PS: and it works fine in Konquerer (which I downloaded to check if it was only a Firefox issue).....